# Set SQL function to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use a variable set to the following request.

```
SUBSTRING( od.RequestName , LEN(od.RequestName) -  CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(od.RequestName)) + 2  , LEN(od.RequestName)  );
```

But, when I declare and set it to a variable, i.e. `vari`, `od` is weird to the SQL runner.

```
declare @vari varchar(100)
set @vari = SUBSTRING( od.RequestName , LEN(od.RequestName) -  CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(od.RequestName)) + 2  , LEN(od.RequestName)  );

SELECT
r.name, p.PageName, @vari
  FROM restable r WITH (NOLOCK) 
       JOIN pestable p WITH (NOLOCK)  ON p.ResourceId = r.ResourceId 
       JOIN odtable od ON od.ResourceCode = p.ResourceCode
```

However, the following works.

```
SELECT
r.name, p.PageName,  
SUBSTRING( od.RequestName , LEN(od.RequestName) -  CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(od.RequestName)) + 2  , LEN(od.RequestName)  )
  FROM restable r WITH (NOLOCK) 
       JOIN pestable p WITH (NOLOCK)  ON p.ResourceId = r.ResourceId 
       JOIN odtable od ON od.ResourceCode = p.ResourceCode
```

Comment: A variable is a *value* not a *macro*.  It is not a substitution of code, so you cannot assign an arbitrary expression to it.

Comment: Hint: `set @vari = SUBSTRING(....)` from where? SQL Server didn't knows where `od.RequestName` comes from

Comment: Variables aren't injected into code, SQL isn't a scripting language like Powershell or Bash, it's a query language. For the variable you have, it would be assigned a scalar value, not an expression which would be calculated later. For the first statement you have, however, the statement will fail as `od.RequestName` has no context in the assignment statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Larnu hmm, thanks for giving insight into the basic point. Further,  how can I achieve this?

Comment: The second statement does what you want, and that the way to do it.

Comment: @Larnu yes, but is not it there a way to call it in a short way, like embedding in a variable, likely to use in multiple places?

Comment: Stop spattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Like I said, SQL isn't a scripting language, @snr . Stop treating it like one.

Comment: @snr You can't do it with only one `variable` as other friends mentioned it. Why don't you try use the `table`?

Comment: @gurkan what do you mean by saying that try to use table? Örnek ile cevaplayabilir misiniz?

Comment: You could define a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you need to use that calculation in other queries.  If you just need to use the result multiple times within a single query, use [cross apply](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) to generate the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with one variable, as other friends have mentioned. But you should use the temp table to facilitate things.

You can create a **temporary table** solely for your basic requirements, so you can reuse it anywhere. Then you may delete it later. I mean, you can combine your requirements in a temporary table. Or different tables for different requirements. Then you can join to other tables.

I used Northwind db to be clearer. First, create a temporary table.

```
create table #temp(
     CategoryId     int
    ,name           nvarchar(50)
    ,length         int
    /*columns for your requirements*/)
```

Then, you load it with what you need like `substring(), len()` or other functions.

```
insert into #temp
select 
     prod.CategoryID
    ,substring(prod.ProductName,1,3) as name
    ,len(prod.ProductName)           as length        
from Products                        as prod
    /*join to different tables too*/
```

After all, you can use it as you wish.

```
select 
     t.*
    ,c.CategoryName
from Categories     as c
inner join #temp    as t on c.CategoryID = t.CategoryId
```

Change these to your cases.

Comment: thank 
 
 
  
             
 
 
 
  
             
 
 
 
  ˘
˘
˘
˘
˘
˘
˘
˘
˘

             
 
 
 
  
             
 
 
 
  
             
 
 
 
  
             
 

you +1

Answer (score 0):

is this how you want?

```
declare @vari varchar(100)

set @vari = (select SUBSTRING( od.RequestName , LEN(od.RequestName) -  
CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(od.RequestName)) + 2  , LEN(od.RequestName)  )

FROM odtable od )
```